# Can i publish a visualforce page on site

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to publish a visualforce page on a site with public access ?

I have a page that works within my org. The page is a form that collects data from users based on a custom object and controller, and insert a new record of that custom object.

Now i need to get this form/page onto a site i created with open access to guests accounts.  The work is that users ( any one) will be able to insert a record of this custom object.

Is that even possible? 
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is possible using a Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, though permissions can be tricky depending on what you need to do with it.

Documentation that can get you started:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites

Steps on how to set up a site:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_setup_overview.htm&language=en_US

There's even youtube videos you can find with a quick search for more info.

Need to choose the page into the available visualform pages of the site

[image]

Comment: I already have a site, but thanks. your link led me to do some more RTFM and find the solution.